# it's 2016, why do I still have to use P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I've been out of the programming game for almost 20 years now but every once in a while I write a app with Visual Studio.

My question is, given .NET has been with us for about 13 years, why should I ***ever*** have to use the native API aka P/Invoke?  Why hasn't everything been converted to official .NET managed assemblies?

Just recently I ran into a situation where I simply want to toggle my Wifi connection on and off without using the mouse.  The keyboard is always faster (for me), yet there is no standard Windows keyboard shortcut for it.  So great, a very simple C# program for me to write.  Imagine my surprise when I found I would have to dip into the native API to this.   I remember having to do this in the early days of .NET --sure, a new technology needs a few years to catch up, right?  Well now it's 2016.

I suppose I just don't see the big picture.  Someone please illuminate me.

Comment: Because there are also UNmanaged languages out there, such as C/C++?

Comment: Because Windows is not written in .NET . Very simple. It is written primarily in C/C++.

Comment: I don't get why unmanaged languages have any bearing as to what is included in .NET.  Give me an example.

Comment: The operating system is not written in a managed language, so wrappers have to be written for all of the operating system functions if you want to call them from a managed language. Which features do you think they should cut from the Windows operating system so that they can write and test all of these managed wrappers?

Comment: The framework does not pretend to cover *everything*.  Some things are just too obscure that they belong in a separate library and does not bog down something as basic as installing .NET.  "Toggling wifi" certainly qualifies, trivial to do from the Windows user interface.  Nuget.org is the usual way to get them.  If you want to do it yourself for some reason then you'll have to do what such a library must do.

Comment: Wouldn't you think that the very basic functions I mentioned would be included in .NET by now?

Comment: Wrapping every function.... MS should be able to do that overnight.  Why is that so difficult?

Comment: See also: [Eric Lippert: How many Microsoft employees does it take to change a lightbulb?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/10/28/how-many-microsoft-employees-does-it-take-to-change-a-lightbulb/) which is written for VBScript but still applies to .Net or anything similar.

Comment: The Windows API changes from Windows version to Windows version. If Microsoft were to wrap every Windows Function, we would need to have different .NET frameworks for every version of Windows.

Comment: @JakobOlsen Not really. You'd handle that with runtime errors when called on an OS version that did not provide the export.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's not the problem .NET was created to solve.  In fact, one could easily argue that with the advent of cross-platform .NET Core, we're going even farther away from this vision.

The Windows API is still alive and well, and under the hood is *the* way Windows is programmed.  Everything implementation-specific about Windows is managed through this API.  For .NET libraries to duplicate every API call, that library set would have to become quite large indeed, and would have to abstract a great many more low-level concepts than they do now.

Every program you use, including the .NET CLR uses the Windows API to do work on Windows.